# How do I solve the 'SpreadsheetNotFound:' without having to add the client_email?

Tags: python, gspread

I'm implementing a routine that open a spreadsheet on Google Drive and copy the data. The code runs once a month on a specific day and the file is added the day before by another person. The problem is the code does not reconise the file name when using gspread. I've seen a solution where you have to share the file to my client_email but because the a new file is added every month, I need to come up with a solution where I don't need to do that everytime.

ps.: the person deletes the current file and add another one with the same name.

My code is:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('test').sheet1

data = sheet.get_all_records()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
```

output:
SpreadsheetNotFound:

Comment: In your case, for example, how about creating the file in the folder which was shared with the service account? Or how about using OAuth2? Each method makes it possible to retrieving the Spreadsheet with the filename. If these were not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: It worked! I hadn't thought about sharing the whole folder instead of one file only. Now that I've shared the whole thing, it is working perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for users who have the same issue.